# What if one of the micro service is down from the services used in apollo gateway?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have two microservices which are User, Country made on apollo graphql. User is dependent on Country because i'm using extending User in Country microservice to fetch the user's country. And I'm using apollo federation and accessing user through apollo gateway. But, if the country service is down, i won't be able access user object even for the rest of data apart from country. I just want to know a way if one of the service is down, how the parent microservice would still be responsive through apollo gateway?

Comment: ... and quick test with your docker containers ...?

Comment: yes, i found out the issue while doing it in docker containers. each service is contained in a docker container.

Comment: your microservices are too tightly coupled - bad design ... show how things are connected / all important details/fragments ... or question is too wide/off topic for SO

Comment: well i thought at some point and one service is going to depend on other service unless we duplicate the data. you can see how these are connected just an example https://gist.github.com/sherazali123/2fef5938538dc1fea8660f74a5daa459

Comment: User resolver should normally return object with countryId defined. You shouldn't be able to resolve user/country using this id - return null for this child/property? Federation doesn't start with one service down at start or stops working? Where is this blocking dependency?

Comment: in country service, `country: Country!` and so the resolver is actually the blocking dependency. how can i write the resolver for countryId in User resolver?

Comment: you claimed user is blocked/unusable ... define field resolver (not already defined in user record/db?) to fetch from relation table?

Comment: I can access user if don't fetch country in User query. Because country's resolver is in another service (with its. own db) which is supposedly down.

Comment: d e t a i l s ... don't [over-]fetch  - you don't need country for login or basic operations ... then this is a client-side tight coupling